# Nuxt.js dynamic 301 redirection's with API matching parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dynamic, http-status-code-301, nuxt.js

I'm trying to 301 redirect old links to new one, the structure of old link is:
http://www.example.com/used/details360?rule=11406

The new one should look like this:

http://www.example.com/cars/{make}/{model}/(rule number from the old link)

**Problem**

I need to use rule number from the incoming old link to call GET API, so I can generate make and model, build a link with that information and 301 redirect to the new one.

And also if the link is dead (404) then it needs to redirect to http://www.example.com/cars

Is that possible?

Comment: Hi 
I have something similar to do, How did you do?